# How to mock the requests made by ngResource in Angular JS

Tags: mocking, jasmine, ngresource

I am trying to begin writing unit tests for my angular application and hit a stopping block pretty quick as I am unsure of how exactly to mock my service in a testable way.
My service is as follows:
var services = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

```
 services.factory('LogonFactory', function ($resource, $http) {
        return $resource('/servicemen/logon/', {}, {
            login: {
                method: 'POST'
            }
       })
  });
```

My test consists thus far of:

```
describe('Logon', function () {
    var mockUserResource, $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            mockLoginResource = $injector.get('login');
        })
    });

    describe('login', function () {
        it('should call login function', inject(function (User) {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('/servicemen/logon/')
                .respond([{
                username: 'test'
            }]);

            var result = mockLoginResource.login();
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(result[0].username).toEqual('test');
        }));

    });
});
```

Also I am getting error No flush !!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing line 8 to mockLoginResource = $injector.get('LogonFactory');